# Можно ли решить следующую цепную дробь при помощи Python?

Tags: python, математика

[image]

Сказали запрограммировать данную бесконечную цепную дробь на Python. Можно ли это сделать и как?

Comment: Не бывает в программировании ничего бесконечного. Ну, конечно же, кроме нежелания новичков на SO гуглить, прежде чем писать сюда, и читать в справке, как правильно оформлять свои вопросы...

Comment: Можно. Поищите примеры по использованию рекурсии

Comment: Рекурсию смотрел, там были только конечные цепные дроби

Comment: А если подробнее: истинно бесконечную – конечно же, нет. Иначе вы будете бесконечно ждать ответа. В любом случае понадобится какое-нибудь "стоп-слово", то есть некое условие, когда пора заканчивать считать. Например, таким условием может стать размер очередного частного в знаменателе. Как? С помощью рекурсии, конечно же.

Comment: Гм. Пусть эта цепная дробь равна x. Видно, что она повторяется как знаменатель, т.е. x = 1 + 1/x - такое уравнение вы на Python решить сможете? Превратив его в квадратное (подсказка)?

Comment: Таким способом я решил. Вопрос как подвязать сюда программирование? Только чтобы найти корни квадратного уравнения?

Comment: Ну если хотите - начинайте с x_i=1 и получайте в цикле x_{i+1} = 1 + 1/x_i, и так до тех пор, пока разница между x_i и x_{i+1} не станет меньше какого-то заранее заданного малого eps. Такое моделирование бесконечной дроби вас устроит?

Comment: А как мы можем взять малое eps, рандомное что ли? В ручную x = (sqrt(5) - 1)/2

Comment: К чему оскорбления? Я хочу понять

Comment: Вам в таком случае я бы порекомендовал научиться хорошим манерам. Не было бы у меня желания понять, как нужно сделать, я бы действительно отправился на фриланс. Я же не просто так задаю вопрос, не прошу готовую программу ничего. Вы же называете меня ленивым и ... .... .... . Вам тоже следует кое-чему научиться, прежде чем учить меня. И это увы не программирование, а что-то человеческое. Удачи

Comment: @SamPlay здравствуйте. дело в том, что это не самый удачный вопрос. вы пробовали это делать? У вас что нибудь получалось до этого? Когда вы пишете вопрос всегда уточняйте что у вас не получается. Но с вами я тоже согласен, ТАК писать человеку некрасиво.

Comment: @alex9127 Дело в том, что я даже не представлял как подступиться к решению, поэтому я не могу и вопрос идеально задать. Сделал это максимально корректно, как мог. Извиняюсь, если не понятно

Comment: @SamPlay ничего страшного. на вопрос вам все равно уже ответили)

Comment: @alex9127 Спасибо за адекватность

Comment: @SamPlay я тоже против всего этого, можно же просто на худой конец объяснить человеку по нормальному

Comment: @alex9127 а потому что многие считают, что тут должны только лишь шарящие люди сидеть, по-моему форум по сути рассчитан для помощи и обсуждению общих вопросов, проблем, а не тому насколько тупой вопрос задан, "ты что гуглить не умеешь"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def f(eps):
    x_i = 1
    x_i1 = 1 + 1 / x_i
    
    while abs(x_i1 - x_i) > eps:
        x_i, x_i1 = x_i1, 1 + 1 / x_i1
    
    return x_i1
```

При желании получить большую точность используйте `Decimal`

```
import decimal

def f(eps):
    x_i = decimal.Decimal(1)
    x_i1 = 1 + 1 / x_i
    
    while abs(x_i1 - x_i) > eps:
        x_i, x_i1 = x_i1, 1 + 1 / x_i1
    
    return x_i1
```

Comment: Спасибо. А можно немного разъяснений, чтобы я понял процесс. Я имею ввиду eps, почему его можно взять самому и какой стоит брать?

Comment: epsilon - сколь угодно малая величина, и такую дробь, как вы представляете вычислить на бесконечности, это же формально будет вычисляться бесконечное время, а по существу, такая дробь только лишь вычислима, пока разница между прошлым и текущим результатом не будет меньше либо равна epsilon, например возьмите eps = 10^-6 посмотрите результат, а потом возьмите 10^-12 и посмотрите результат

Comment: @SamPlay, берите в зависимости от того, сколько точных знаков после запятой хотите.